# Counting the times of recursion in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion, counting

I am writing a small school assignment in Haskell to determine the distance between two given dates. I wrote a crude function to cycle through dates but I can't wrap my head around how to write loops in a Functional Programming way. I have only done  procedural- and OOP-programming before. I somehow need to store the information of how many times I've called the nextDate-function but Haskell doesn't allow me to introduce a variable inside a function. Here is the code I've come up so far. It is not very Haskelly at all...

```
nextDate year month day = 
    if day + 1 < 31
        then (year,month, day+1)
    else if month + 1 < 12
        then (year, month + 1, 1)
    else (year +1,1,1)

calculateDifference year month day year2 month2 day2 = 
    let x = 0
    if year == year2 && month == month2 && day == day2 then x
    else 
     nextDate(year, month, day)
     x = x + 1

    -- How I would do it in Python
    -- x = 0
    -- while((tuple1) != (year2, month2, day2)):
    --  x += 1
    --  tuple1 = nextDate(tuple1)
    -- print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the recursion times in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791904/how-to-count-the-recursion-times-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track how many times the function is called, you need to provide that as an input. There's no other way to do this, because Haskell only lets you work with arguments that are passed into the function.

For example, let's say I wanted to compute a factorial, but I wanted to track how many steps it took. My function signature could look like this:

```hs
factorial :: Int -> (Int, Int) -- Takes a number, returns the number and recursion count
factorialInternal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -- This actually does the recursion
```

and then the definitions could look like this:

```hs
factorial n = factorialInternal (n, 0)
factorialInternal (1, n) = (1, n + 1)
factorialInternal (x, n) = let (y, z) = factorialInternal (x-1, n) in (x * y, z + 1)
```

Essentially, the parameter tracking the amount of recursion is incremented at each level, and then becomes part of the output of `factorial`.

It definitely helps to create an interface function so that you don't have to manually input the starting recursion level when using the function (which is always zero, anyway). An example of what your function signatures could look like:

```hs
-- The function you call
calculateDifference :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
-- What the calculateDifference function calls (the third parameter is the recursion counter)
calculateDifferenceInternal :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Int -> Int
```

From here, you should be able to figure out how to implement `calculateDifference` and `calculateDifferenceInternal`.

---

EDIT: As amalloy pointed out, a better solution is to just output the counter, not take one in: so instead of `factorialInternal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)`, `factorialInternal Int -> (Int, Int)` would work. The definition would then look like:

```hs
factorialInternal 1 = (1, 0)
factorialInternal n = let (x, y) = factorialInternal (n - 1) in (n * x, y + 1)
```

Comment: "There's no other way to do this" - not quite: you can do this with a new output and no new input. In the base case, return 0 for your counter, and in recursive cases add 1 to the result produced by the recursive call.

Comment: You're right, that's another approach to this problem. I'll edit my answer and add that in.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say my suggestion is better. It is different, and will perform better for some functions but worse for others. It's just good to know about both.